# Guardar textos en una tupla en una posicion aleatoria (y optimizacion de codigo)

Tags: python, optimización

Tengo un ejercicio  que dice así:

> Escribe un programa que guarde un texto en una posición aleatoria de una tupla de 10 datos

Por ejemplo, escribo el texto : `"texto de prueba"`. El texto se guardo en la posición 8 (generada aleatoriamente) de la tupla.

Para generar la posición uso la función de generar números aleatorios.
El problema  es que quiero generar esos números pero *sin que se repitan*,
es decir que salga el uno y que en el ciclo no se vuelva a repetir ese mismo.

Y también si me dieran un tip para ir tratando de *reducir las lineas de código* porque este ejercicio consumirá mucha memoria. Y originalmente la tupla era de 100 datos.

Este es mi código:

```
import random
#Variables para posiciones
p1=1
p2=2
p3=3
p4=4
p5=5
p6=6
p7=7
p8=8
p9=9
p10=10
#Contador
C=0
#Tupla con sus posiciones
tupla=(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10)
band=True
#Ciclo para ir generando numeros hasta el 10
while band:
    entrada = str(input("Ingrese un texto: "))
    #Genera un numero aleatorio para guardarlo en una posicion
    pos = random.randint(1,10)

    C = C+1
    #Nucleo del programa
if pos==p1:
    p1=entrada
    tupla = (p1)
    print ("Su texto se guardo en la posición 1 y dice:" ,p1 )
elif pos==p2:
    p2=entrada
    tupla = (p1,p2)
    print ("Su texto se guardo en la posición 2 y dice:" ,p2 )
elif pos==p3:
    p3=entrada
    tupla = (p1,p2,p3)
    print ("Su texto se guardo en la posición 3 y dice:" ,p3 )
elif pos==p4:
    p4=entrada
    tupla = (p1,p2,p3,p4)
    print ("Su texto se guardo en la posición 4 y dice:" ,p4 )
elif pos==p5:
    p5=entrada
    tupla = (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5)
    print ("Su texto se guardo en la posición 5 y dice:" ,p5 )
elif pos==p6:
    p6=entrada
    tupla = (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6)
    print ("Su texto se guardo en la posición 6 y dice:" ,p6 )
elif pos==p7:
    p7=entrada
    tupla = (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7)
    print ("Su texto se guardo en la posición 7 y dice:" ,p7 )
elif pos==p8:
    p8=entrada
    tupla = (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p5,p6,p7,p8)
    print ("Su texto se guardo en la posición 8 y dice:" ,p8 )
elif pos==p9:
    p9=entrada
    tupla = (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9)
    print ("Su texto se guardo en la posición 9 y dice:" ,p9 )
elif pos==p10:
    p10=entrada
    tupla = (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10)
    print ("Su texto se guardo en la posición 10 y dice:" ,p10 )
if C==10:
    band= False
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque una tupla no se puede modificada, podemos guardar las entradas en una lista (no directamente a una tupla), y luego convertirla a una tupla.
Tambien utilizo una lista para que los numeros aleatorios no se repitan.

El codigo:

```py
import random

# Crea una lista para selectar el posision de manera aleatorio
listaPosicion = list(range(1,11)) #[1,2,...,10]
# Crea una lista para guardar entradas. Luego, convertimos listaFinal a una tupla
listaFinal =  list(range(1,11)) #[1,2,...,10]

while listaPosicion != []:
    entrada = str(input("Ingrese un texto: "))

    # Obtener un numero aleatorio de listaPosicion, y luego eliminar este numero de la lista (para que no lo seleccionamos una vez mas)
    posicion = random.choice(listaPosicion)
    listaPosicion.remove(posicion)

    # Guardar en listaFinal
    listaFinal[posicion - 1] = entrada

    # Convertir la listaFinal a una tupla
    tuplaFinal = tuple(listaFinal)
    print(tuplaFinal)
    print ("Su texto se guardo en la posicion {} y dice: {}".format(posicion, entrada))

input()
```